# Code coverage for phpunit

Tags: selenium, phpunit, code-coverage

1) I used the selenium with phpunit ,I tried to used the code coverage for phpunit but I have one doubt.Is this code coverage is used for only unit test (or) functional test
2) If i used code coverage in phpunit with selenium but its not covered the code 
then the result is 0% covered, pls give any clarification to me.
Example Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coverage generated="1381493785">
  <project timestamp="1381493785">
    <metrics files="0" loc="0" ncloc="0" classes="0" methods="0" coveredmethods="0" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="0" coveredstatements="0" elements="0" coveredelements="0"/>
  </project>
</coverage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code coverage should only be generated when executing unit tests. And I believe PHPUnit can only create code coverage when directly executing the code to be covered. When using Selenium, the code is only executed indirectly (possibly on a different machine), and cannot be covered.

So why only for unit tests? It's because code coverage is supposed to help you spot lines that are not tested with a unit test.

Why not in functional tests? Because these are there to prove that the sum of all parts works together, not iterate through every possible combination of input to get a full coverage. It might be even impossible, because the input that would trigger an error condition inside a model cannot even reach that because the form validation already stops execution.